# Mobile home page titles are different sizes

Tags: bug

When I view on mobile I see two text sizes, with no apparent reason why.

[image: skeptics home page mobile snap]

You can see some have been visited and some not, so I don't think this is a design choice. I checked other SE sites and it is the same.

If I had my pick, I prefer the bigger text to be the default.

I'm using a Samsung S8 with Chrome.

Comment: I just use the full responsive site now. If you're getting mobile when you login, scroll to the bottom and click "full site".